# Problems with ansible 2.7.9 using host_vars (undefined variable)

Tags: variables, ansible, host

Ansible 2.7.9 is not using host_vars

Ive setup a very simple setup with 3 hosts, mainly for testing purposes . I have hosts :

```
- ansible1 (this is where I store the code)
- ansible2
- ansible3
```

My inventory :

```
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/hosts
[common]
ansible1
ansible2
ansible3
```

My cfg looks like that :

```
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
roles_path = /etc/ansible/roles
inventory  = /etc/ansible/hosts
[privilege_escalation]
[paramiko_connection]
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
control_path = /tmp/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
pipelining = False
[accelerate]
[selinux]
[colors]
```

I have defined a master playbook called common which calls common :

```
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ ls /etc/ansible/roles/
common  common.retry  common.yml
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/roles/common.yml
--- # Playbook for webservers
- hosts: common
  roles:
    - common
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$
```

The task/main.yml :

```
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml
- name: test ansible1
  lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/ansible.txt
    create: yes
    line: "{{ myvar }}"
- name: set ansible2
  lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/ansible2.txt
    create: yes
    line: "hi"
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$

[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/roles/common/vars/main.yml
copyright_msg: "Copyrighta 2019"
myvar: "value of myvar from common/vars"
```

THen I placed some info at /etc/ansible/host_vars

```
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ ls /etc/ansible/hosts_vars/
ansible2.yml
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/hosts_vars/ansible2.yml
myvar: "myvar from host_vars"
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$
```

This works great with playbook :

```
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/roles/common.yml --limit ansible2

PLAY [common] ******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [ansible2]

TASK [common : test ansible1] **************************************************
changed: [ansible2]

TASK [common : set ansible2] ***************************************************
changed: [ansible2]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ansible2                   : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I see the file with the content of myvar :

```
[root@ansible2 ~]# cat /tmp/ansible.txt
value of myvar from common/vars
[root@ansible2 ~]#
```

But then I dont understand why it is not taking the value from /etc/ansible/hosts_vars/ansible2.yml , in fact if I comment the line from /etc/ansible/roles/common/vars/main.yml it says undefined variable :

```
[ansible@ansible1 ansible]$ cat /etc/ansible/roles/common/vars/main.yml
copyright_msg: "Copyrighta 2019"
myvar: "value of myvar from common/vars"
```

Comment: Ansible 2.8.1: `hosts_vars` (plural) is now discarded as invalid. Only `host_vars` works.

Comment: Yes, it was just a typo, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible uses that priority for values from vars :

```
From least to most important
role defaults
inventory file or script group vars
inventory group_vars/all
playbook group_vars/all
inventory group_vars/*
playbook group_vars/*
inventory file or script host vars
inventory host_vars/*
playbook host_vars/*
host facts
play vars
play vars_prompt
play vars_files
role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)
block vars (only for tasks in block)
task vars (only for the task)
role (and include_role) params
include params
include_vars
set_facts / registered vars
extra vars (always win precedence)
```

So is better to forget about using roles/vars because it takes precedence over host_vars, so I should use instead roles/defaults, which has a lower priority .

Answer (score 3):

This is as expected the main.yml will get sourced automatically while executing the playbook. consider this file as global variables.

The reason ansible2.yml is not getting sourced is because ansible expects you to source that explicitly while executing.

You can use below code for that(generic).

```
---
- name: play
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  tasks:
    - include_vars: "{{ hosts }}.yml"
```

trigger -->

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory --extra-vars "hosts=ansible2"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I understand what you say about the suffix/file extension , I would like to ask what would be the most correct file to put the include_vars ?

Comment: Since you will be passing the hosts value to the play while executing based on host vars I would suggest to use the same variable for include_vars: editing my answer

Comment: Actually Im using --limit ansible2 in order to output a more convenient and clear output , but what Im trying to achieve is something similar to what I had with puppet/hiera , I want default values from roles/vars (thats working) but I want to get if I need values from host level (but I dont want them to be at the CLI level ) to averride the ones from roles/rolename/vars

Comment: limit is used for executing the tasks on a single host from a host group you can use hosts variable as well. Now for if same variable is declared in main.yml and ansible2.yml --> ansible2.yml will take precedence. similar to facter in puppet we have ansible facts which gathers information per host and can be used dynamically.

Comment: Hello, I really apreciate the help here . Actually its not working, I did what you posted : 
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set
I just modified the masterplaybook to include the code :
[ansible@ansible1 roles]$ cat /etc/ansible/roles/common.yml
--- # Playbook for webservers
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
- tasks:
  - include_vars: "{{ hosts }}"
  roles:
    - common
[ansible@ansible1 roles]$

Comment: Also I have defined the host name with the content :
[ansible@ansible1 roles]$ cat /etc/ansible/hosts_vars/ansible2
myvar: "myvar from host_vars"
[ansible@ansible1 roles]$

Comment: I think I found the problem, the task dash . Now it seems like ansible is not able to find the file at host_vars :
[ansible@ansible1 roles]$ ansible-playbook common.yml --extra-vars "hosts=ansible2" --limit ansible2
fatal: [ansible2]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "Could not find or access 'ansible2'\nSearched in:\n\t/etc/ansible/roles/vars/ansible2\n\t/etc/ansible/roles/ansible2\n\t/etc/ansible/roles/vars/ansible2\n\t/etc/ansible/roles/ansible2 on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expee

Comment: @Flechoide Seems like you have not included the .yml at the end. include_vars: "{{ hosts }}.yml"

Comment: Yes thats true, but the file also lacks the .yml extension : 
/etc/ansible/hosts_vars/ansible2

Comment: Can you try two things. 1 provide the path argument to the include_vars file as I can't see the directory where ansible tries to search to be the path you have placed the file..2. if the above doesn't work can you provide an extension and path argument to the include_vars module

Comment: Thats my dir structure :
Base ansible dir :
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ ls /etc/ansible/
ansible.cfg  hosts  hosts_vars  roles

Roles dir uder base ansible:
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ ls /etc/ansible/roles/
common  common.retry  common.yml  common.yml.20190410

Hosts_var under base ansible
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ ls /etc/ansible/hosts_vars/
ansible2

I have my cfg as this , so from documentation it says everthing is relative to the host inventory file:
[ansible@ansible1 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
roles_path = /etc/ansible/roles
inventory  = /etc/ansible/hosts

Comment: Also I tried to place the directory at the yml but it still doesnt work, however now it is not showing any error , just uses the variable value from /etc/ansible/roles/common//vars/main.yml instead of the value from /etc/ansible/hosts_vars/ansible2 :
--- # Playbook for webservers
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  tasks:
  - include_vars: "/etc/ansible/hosts_vars/{{ hosts }}"
  roles:
    - common

Comment: Hi there, it worked when I changed from hosts_vars to host_var , my typo error, and I commented the var definition from /etc/ansibleroles/common/vars/main.yml , so the problem seems to be that roles/module/vars/main.yml takes precedence over hosts_Vars

Comment: I can confirm that now changing hosts_vars to host_var is working . THe problema is that the value defined in /etc/ansible/host_vars/ansible2.yml is not taking precedence over the value defined at /etc/ansible/roles/common/vars/main.yml

Comment: Yes, ansible works in that way same variable if defined the precedence will to as per ansible guidelines

Comment: @Flechoide what are you exactly looking for ?

Comment: I just wanted to achieve something similar as what I have with puppet with hierarchical values, I thank you , yu helped me a lot